# No idea why this error is occurring "Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before \\cventry was complete"

Tags: errors, moderncv

```
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
....
\cventry{2004}{Secondary School}{ABC School}{Cityname}{\textit{94.4/100}}
...
```

WriteLatex gives me this error

```
Runaway argument?
Paragraph ended before \\cventry was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.72
```

I dont know why this occurrs, If I comment out all the Education \cventry fields, then it compiles properly. But I cant leave the education field blank in my CV, so Please help.

Comment: Hi! I don't think it's possible to help you without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: This warning is caused by one of the following **duplicate newlines**,  **too few curly braced arguments** or **block comments** to the right of to `\cventry`.  The warning is presented on the first instance of `\cventry` even if the offending cventry is lower down in the document.  bazinga.

Answer (score 14):

Your `cventry` has only 5 arguments. It needs to have 6:

```
\cventry{2004}{Secondary School}{ABC School}{Cityname}{\textit{94.4/100}}{}
```

Comment: Missing the extra argument is the key. Thanks!